# Git doesn't recognize that files don't have changes

Tags: git

I have two files that are showing up as "modified" even when they are not; the reason I'm sure is because if I clone the repository, there shouldn't be any changes related between the remote and local. Isn't it?

Now, I know I have a `.gitattributes` file:

```
#
# Set the default behavior, in case people don't have core.autocrlf set
* text eol=lf

#
# Denote all files that are truly binary and should not be modified
*.gif binary
*.ico binary
```

...that's imposing the line-ends to `LF` (UN*X), and I know my files are `CRLF` (Windows), but again, there shouldn't be any differences between them when I clone the repo from the very first time, although I know that file, at `checkout` imposes it.

So, is there any way I can tell `.gitattributes` NOT to care about several files, something like:

```
src/main/resources/db/migration/V1__sample01.sql text eol=crlf
```

**NOTE:** I can't delete the files and recreate them because I'm using Flyway and it does recognize if the files are changed just by merely changing the line ends.

---

**UPDATE:** I wasn't able to specify that *per file* (as a work-around); anyway, now I'm able to change those files into `LF` since we upgraded to Flyway 4.X and it doesn't check file checksums anymore.

Comment: I don't use Windows and have not experimented with these conversions, but I believe that the `.gitattributes` conversions actually work during `git checkout` and `git add`. Since the last thing `git clone` does is `git checkout` whatever you asked it to check out, if the `.gitattributes` file exists in that checkout, it seems that repository copies will be modified according to those directives, and then re-modified in the `add` direction for later check-in. If that changes what's in the commit that `clone` is checking out, those files would be "modified" (since they will be on a new commit).

Comment: (ran out of room, so, continued comment) The interesting questions then are: (1) is the `.gitattributes` in the commit you are checking out, and (2) what's actually in the version of the files in that commit (without any filtering imposed, i.e., what would be checked out if there were no `.gitattributes`)?

Comment: The `.gitattributes` is indeed in the `origin/master`, so yes, it's in the checkout that I'm making. If something is happening, it's happening in `git checkout`...I think I would have to remove the `.gitattributes` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in "[Dealing with line endings (Windows)](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/#per-repository-settings)", the `.gitattributes` directives will be applied on checkout.

So either accept the lf conversion (`git add .`, `git push`) in order to have all text files with LF EOL.

Or remove the `* text eol=lf` directive from the `.gitattributes` files, add just this file, push it, and clone again the repo to check that no file is changed on checkout.

Comment: I know that will fix it...but temporarily because I have to change that setting back to `eol=lf` after `git checkout`.

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ If you push the new gitattributes (with the `* text eol=lf`  removed), you won't have the eol issue atthe next checkout.